# How to Optimize A query with Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a query which applies inner join on 540 million records table. This query took time more than 9 hrs.

I want to optimize the query, how can I handle that.

Query is-

```
Delete top(1000)
FROM table1 fact
INNER JOIN
table2 uu
ON uu.User1 = fact.User1
Where uu.Is_Archived$ = 'true' 
and fact.Snapshot_Date$Snapshot_Date$ > uu.User_End_Date$
```

Columns used in join are integers and both columns have same data type. and there has many invalid number of records.

Any help would be great. Thanks!!!

Comment: Information about the structure of your tables is very important when it comes to optimizing queries.

Comment: Does your query really work?  I would think `from table name` would be needed after the `delete`.

Comment: Columns used in join are integers and both columns have same data type. and there has many invalid number of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `delete` is really:

```
Delete top(1000) from fact
    FROM table1 fact INNER JOIN
         table2 uu
         ON uu.User1 = fact.User1
     Where uu.Is_Archived$ = 'true' and
           fact.Snapshot_Date$Snapshot_Date$ > uu.User_End_Date$;
```

Then indexes should help the query.  One possibility is:  `table1(Snapshot_Date$Snapshot_Date$, User1)` and `table2(User1, IsArchived$)`.  Another is `table2(IsArchived$, User1)` and `table1(User1, Snapshot_Date$Snapshot_Date$)`.